# How do you convert .cer file to pfx format in Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

We currently have the following command that converts a .cer certificate file to .pfx format:

certutil -f -p "somepw,somepw" -mergepfx "c:\temp\stage_cert.cer" "c:\temp\stage.pfx"

This works fine when run in our ci/cd pipeline server.

I am trying to do the same thing on my local machine, but I keep getting this error:

CertUtil: -MergePFX command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

The .cer file is in that temp folder. What is it not finding?